# <%: %> vs Microsoft the anti XSS library

Tags: asp.net, antixsslibrary

With .net 4 there's a new <%: %> script enclosure that's like <%= %> but does an html encode.  People are encouraging the use of this new syntax.

My question is, does <%: %> protect against XSS better or as well as using the Microsoft Anti XSS library?

A Microsoft security person once told me to never just use HTML Encode as it doesn't protect very well and that I should always use the Anti XSS library (or another library).  Is that still true with <%: %>?  Or can I confidently use <%: %> knowing it's going to protect my app from XSS like people are saying?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility_members.aspx) uses a black list (principle of exclusions) approach to encoding, which potentially leaves the door ajar for newly discover exploits in the future. The **[Anti-XSS library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)** (now known as the Web Protection Library and includes code to mitigate SQL injection too)  uses a whitelist approach (principle of inclusions) which closes the door a little further and should provide better security.

`<%: ... %>` is just a shortcut for `<%= Server.HtmlEncode(string) %>` and therefore provides the security of the encoder used in your application.

You can use any encoder you like with the new `<%: ... %>` syntax and Phil Haack has a great post on **[hooking up the Anti-Xss library as the default encoder](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx)**. Bear in mind that currently Anti-XSS library 3.1 requires medium trust to run - this is being addressed for a future release.

Comment: I didn't know that about hooking up <%: %> to a different encoder.  That is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

The new syntax should only be used to escape raw text content in HTML.  **EDIT**: and attributes.

For <strike>attributes,</strike> Javascript, and other contexts, you should still use the Anti-XSS library,

Comment: The Anti-XSS library provides safer encoding for HTML and attribute encoding as well